# How to generate unique alpha-numeric string in php at time(with predefine length [length = 6])

Tags: php, string, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to generate 6 character long alpha numeric string in php.

I'm getting question and answers on stackoverflow.

[shorturl on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027972/php-generating-unique-string)

[Random string generate in php but not unique string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356289/php-random-string-generator)

[Random, unique string generate in php but didn't unique at time with 6  length of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846202/php-how-to-generate-a-random-unique-alphanumeric-string)

Can I generate more 1 Lacs string at time,

```
$arr = [];
$matchStr = [];
for($i=1;$i<=10000;$i++){
    $saltString = "ap_";
    $dynamicStr = substr(md5($saltString.$i), 26, 32);
    do{
       $arr[$i] = $dynamicStr;
    }while(!in_array($dynamicStr,$arr));
}
```

I'm generate strings possible to all ways but didn't get unique string and store into mysql table with unique index of column.

I know possibility of generate of string is:

```
$str = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
```

Random String Possibility:
length of string: 10

a-z  = 26

A-Z  = 26

0-9  = 10

(26+26+10)^10 = 8.3929937 x 10^17 possibility at time.

is that any solution for generate string at time?
in laravel trying with below code

```
function getrandomstr() {
    $length = 6;
    $characters = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $string = "";

    for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
       @$string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))];
    }
    return $string;
}
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
$arr = [];
$matchStr = [];
$query = [];
for($i=1;$i<=100000;$i++){
   $str = getrandomstr();
   do{
      $query[] = [
          "hashcode" => $str
     ];
   }while(\App\Model::where('hashcode',$str)->count() == 0);
}
foreach(array_chunk($query,5000) as $a){
    \App\Model::insert($a);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "php at time"?

Comment: Why don't yu want to use http://php.net/manual/ru/function.uniqid.php

Answer (score 0):

```
function getrandomstr() {
    $length = 6;
    $characters = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $string = "";

    for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
        @$string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))];
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Comment: @DhavalTasol: It does generate a random string within the constraints you have defined (6 character, alpha-numeric). It cannot return a MySQL error, since it doesn't use MySQL - that error comes from somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Your code is incorrect! It might return shorter strings due to wrong using of `mt_rand`. The rand function may return any integer from 0 to max (`strlen($characters)` in this case) including, but `strlen($characters)` is greater than the max index of `$characters` string (since indexes start from 0). The correct line will be: `$string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];`

Answer (score 0):

If you want an unique identifier for each row in a database, use a simple automatically incrementing integer. If you don't want an integer use the `UUID()` function in MySQL, which will give you a complex string that is practically unique.

If you want to be able to generate a random string within strict constraints (6 character alpha-numeric) that is guaranteed to be unique, you will need to compare it to all the existing keys in the database before/while inserting it. Just using a random string generator will eventually generate a duplicate since there is a finite set of results, how often depends on your constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at [Hashids](https://github.com/vinkla/hashids). It's a simple laravel package (well, a wrapper for http://hashids.org/).

After you add the package go to config and change salt and the rest to this

```
'main' => [
    'salt' => 'your-salt-string',
    'length' => '6',
    'alphabet' => '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
],
```

And simply use like this:

```
Hashids::encode(123456);
```